# Failed to build Python packages when installing Python on AIX

Tags: python, installation, aix

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to install python 2.6.8 from source code on an AIX 6.5 machine. I built with these commands:

```
CC=gcc CXX=g++ ./configure --enable-shared
make
```

And I get these errors:

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_sqlite3           bsddb185           dl              
imageop            linuxaudiodev      ossaudiodev     
spwd               sunaudiodev                        
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_bsddb             _ctypes            _curses         
_curses_panel      _tkinter           fcntl
```

Where can I find these "bits" and how can I install them into python? Could you give some detailed guide? I have no root right. Thanks.

**Update**

I try to compile python with xlc:

```
CC=xlc_r OPT="-O2 -qmaxmem=70000" ./configure --without-computed-gotos --enable-shared
make
```

Also get the same error.

**Update2**

I try to compile python 2.7.3 with xlc also get error but `fcntl` and `_bsddb` are build successfully.

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           bsddb185        
dl                 imageop            linuxaudiodev   
ossaudiodev        spwd               sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_ctypes            _curses            _curses_panel   
_tkinter
```